# PWA SCope dont hide address bar

Tags: javascript, android, progressive-web-apps

I want to hide address bar in my PWA App, app installs fine and is working fine but in upper section I can't hide address bar, my app is in main folder on server, so I did it like that:

```
"name": "Kontrola Parkingu",
"short_name": "Kontrola Parkingu",
"start_url": "./login.php",
"scope": "./",
"display": "fullscreen",
"description": "Progressive Web App.",
"background_color": "#4c0b0b",
"theme_color": "#4c0b0b",
"orientation": "portrait-primary",
```

I was trying to change scope to ../public/ but does not work.
 Standalone display mode does not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed Sbai, When you publish the assetslink in the root of your domain (it has to be https), and generate a new version in the google console, the address bar disappears. You can find more details at https://dev.to/hyunseunglee2008/twa-apps-how-to-hide-the-url-bar-browser-bar-and-display-app-as-full-screen-4cm3. good lucky